# How to set width and height of a chart in pixels?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

Setting width and height of the `ChartObject` or its `Shape` doesnt do it. They both seem to be just some inner part of that white rectangle which is the embedded chart. Also the `ChartArea` doesn't seem to be the object I'm interested in.

I want the exported file in the following example to have dimensions 800x600 (and I don't mean rescaling the exported image or trial and error until the size accidentally fits). There must be some object around the chart which I have overlooked.

```
Sub mwe()

Dim filepath As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim cObj As ChartObject
Dim c As Chart
Dim cShape As Shape
Dim cArea As chartArea

filepath = Left(ThisWorkbook.FullName, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.FullName, "\"))
Set sheet = ActiveSheet
Set cObj = sheet.ChartObjects(1)
Set c = cObj.chart
Set cShape = sheet.Shapes(cObj.Name)
Set cArea = c.chartArea

cObj.Width = 800
cObj.Height = 400
MsgBox cArea.Width & " x " & cArea.Height  '793x393
c.Export filepath & "test1.png"            '1067x534, this is also the size on screen

cShape.Width = 800
cShape.Height = 400
MsgBox cArea.Width & " x " & cArea.Height  '794x393
c.Export filepath & "test2.png"            '1068x534, this is also the size on screen

End Sub
```

update:

It turns out the `ChartObject` and the `Shape` belonging to the same `Chart` already have the `Worksheet` as parent but width and height are not specified in pixels but in points, where 1 point = 1/72 inches, and most of the time, Windows seems to assume 96 pixels per inch.

Thanks to Steve's comment I am now using the following, which is quite reliable.

A `ChartObject` that is not activated at the moment of export seems to produce a file where width and height is 1 higher than it should be.

It remains to find out how to determine the factors `px2ptH` and `px2ptV` automatically.

```
Sub mwe()

Dim filepath As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim cObj As ChartObject
Dim c As Chart

Dim px2ptH As Double: px2ptH = 72 / 96
Dim px2ptV As Double: px2ptV = 72 / 96
Dim w As Double: w = 800 * px2ptH
Dim h As Double: h = 400 * px2ptV

filepath = Left(ThisWorkbook.FullName, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.FullName, "\"))
Set sheet = ActiveSheet
Set cObj = sheet.ChartObjects(1)
Set c = cObj.Chart

'otherwise image size may deviate by 1x1
cObj.Activate

cObj.Width = w
cObj.Height = h

c.Export filepath & "test.png"

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not adding `debug.print cobj.parent.name` just after setting cObj ? that should give you the right hint.

Comment: I think the reason that you are not getting exactly 800 x 400 is that excel uses inches and not pixels and the accuracy is .01 inch and because of that you don get exactly 800 by 400!

Comment: Since you've correctly indicated that the exported picture is sized based upon how it currently appears on the screen, you cannot realistically expect to be able to control the size of the file. Even if you zoom in or out on your sheet, this effects the size of the file. I do not believe you can change this without having a far more complicated solution. I'd suggest making sure you're dimensions are correct and then resizing the file as needed.

Comment: @iDevlop: it gives the name of the worksheet. so it's not an enclosing object we're looking for. but what else is at play here? is the default unit for width and height not pixels but mm or something?

Comment: @daniel: it is exported based on its appearance on screen on 100% (if i view it at 200% and export, the size in the file doesnt change). and i think i can expect to set the size in pixels. why not?

Comment: @hooman: i dont see how such an accuracy issue can cause 800 vs 1067.

Comment: The dimensions are in points, not pixels.  72 points to the inch.  800 pixels / 72 = 11.11111....  The size of the exported image will be the size in inches/the dpi of your computer's display, usually 96 (as it is in your case, but you can't always count on it ... use WIN API calls to find the current value)

Comment: @steve: that's it. if i scale by 72/96, i get the correct size. on this machine at least. do you happen to know the necessary winapi calls you speak of? maybe you could make an answer out of your comment and include and example of how to get that 96. i could probably read the image file and go from there, but that's not clean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dimensions are in points, not pixels. 72 points to the inch.

800 pixels / 72 = 11.11111.... The size of the exported image will be the size in inches/the dpi of your computer's display, usually 96 (as it is in your case, but you can't always count on it ... use WIN API calls to find the current value)

Randy Birch has published code you can use to access the WinAPI calls to get screen resolution and more.

Go to http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html and use the search feature on the left to look up GETDEVICECAPS

Comment: perfect, i added the solution to my question.